# Model using Euler method and pointer arithmetic not functioning

Tags: c, pointers, model, while-loop

I'm new to C, and quite unfamiliar with writing any program larger than a few lines.

I'm trying to write a model for an object in freefall acted upon by gravity and drag. It uses Eulers method to solve two first order differential equations, one for position and one for velocity.

So we have: F = m dv/dt = -mg - k|v|v and dy/dt = v

These are solved by: Vn+1 = Vn - (delta t*(g+(k/m)|Vn|Vn)) and Yn+1 = Yn + (delta t * Vn)

(In this Vn+1 is the n+1th term etc.)

In my program i've tried to have two functions, for position and velocity, which work by passing pointers with Y and V values between them and the main function, and it should then loop until Y=0 and print off the values at each step.

When I run it it comes up with something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gT4i1.jpg

Could anyone tell me either what is wrong with this, or if I need to use a different approach completely?

Many Thanks, Code below

```
#include <stdio.h>

void Velocity(double *ptr, double m, double k, double t);
void Position(double *pst, double *ptr, double t );

int main()
{
double k = 18833.5608;
double t = 0;
double m;
double speed = 0;
double *ptr = &speed;
double y = 1000;
double *pst = &y;

printf("Enter mass of object: \n");
scanf("%f" , &m);

do
{
Velocity( ptr, m, k, t );
printf("Velocity at time %f is: %f\n" , t, speed);
Position( pst, ptr, t);
printf("Position at time %f is: %f\n" , t , y);
t++;
}
while((y>0));

return 0;
}

void Velocity(double *velo, double m, double k, double t)
{
double g = 9.80665;
*velo = *velo - (t*(g+((k/m)*fabs(*velo)**(velo))));
}

void Position(double *Y , double *velo, double t )
{
*Y =  *Y+(t*(*velo));
}
```

Comment: Why are you using pointers?

Comment: As I said, I'm new to this so it looks like ive taken a misstep in doing so. Could you let me know of an easier way to do this? Thanks

Comment: And the formula you're using are very rough estimates, especially using delta t of 1. And you're using it wrong. You should use the incremental of time, not the absolute time, in both formulas. Otherwise the rough estimate just get farther and farther from the correct value. Let me try to show

Comment: yeah the time was just set to be simple until I could get the other parts working. I couldnt think of how to increment the time and include that

Answer (score 1):

When writing programs that do calculations -- in any language, not just C -- try to make the code that does the computation *take arguments* and *return results* but not *mutate variables*. That is, do not write:

```
void do_calculation( double * result, double x, double y)
{
    *result = x + y;
}
...
double r;
do_calculation(&r, 123, 456);
```

instead write

```
double do_calculation(double x, double y)
{
    return x + y;
}
...
double r = do_calculation(123, 456);
```

Make sense?

If you want to modify an existing value, again, don't pass it in as a variable to be mutated. Instead of

```
void do_calculation(double * accumulator, double x, double y)
{
    *accumulator = *accumulator + x + y;
}
...
double r = 10;
do_calculation(&r, 123, 456);
```

instead say

```
double do_calculation(double original, double x, double y)
{
    return original + x + y;
}
...
double r = 10;
r = do_calculation(r, 123, 456);
```

Now, once you've got your program architected more sensibly, you need to learn how to debug small programs. Some good advice on that subject can be found here:

http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Makes sense, but there's nothing wrong in trying to change variables through functions. For this application, I agree that the best practice would to do as you say. But imagine that to sort a list you would actually generate a new one sorted, what a waste of memory

Comment: @Inox: first, memory is cheap and plentiful. Second, immutable lists can in some cases massively save on memory because they allow you to re-use existing state. Third, yes, many methods are best characterized as *mutating the state of a data structure*, but the method shown here is not; it's a "pure" method whose outputs depend only on its inputs.

Answer (score 0):

A misconcept. I believe you're trying to solve the equations by using small increments of time. Nothing wrong with that, just make the time increment as small as possible, and correct the formulas:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void Velocity(double *velocity, double m, double k, double t)
{
double g = 9.80665;
double velo = *(velocity);
velo = velo - (t*(g+((k/m)*abs(velo)*(velo))));
*(velocity)=velo;
}

void Position(double *position , double *velocity, double t )
{
double Y = *(position);
double velo = *(velocity);
Y =  Y+(t*(velo));
*(position)=Y;
}

int main()
{
double k = 18833.5608;
double t = 0;
double dt = 0.001; //making a small increment of time
double m=100;
double speed = 0;
double y = 1000;


//printf("Enter mass of object: \n");
//scanf("%f" , &m);

do
{
Velocity( &speed, m, k, dt );
printf("Velocity at time %f is: %f\n" , t, speed);
Position( &y, &speed, dt);
printf("Position at time %f is: %f\n" , t , y);
t+=dt; //increment time by delta t
}
while((y>0));

return 0;
}
```

Comment: see if it works, the idea of the formulas were correct. Using pointers (though possibly correctly done) is unnecessary. The implementation of the formula, using t, was wrong

Comment: By the way, as the dt is very small, you might want to print the results just in multiples of x iterations

Comment: And your k is really big, you might have the value in a different unit (rather than kg/m)

Comment: Thanks, yeah pointers seemed the right way to go but I think I just misunderstood their importance. This looks a lot better!

Comment: Pointers are good for some applications, especially when you need to point to things, such as linked lists or arrays. In your case, they weren't necessary. Is it working now?

Comment: The incrementing and time display works, but the values are stuck at 1000 and 0 for position and velocity

Comment: You're right. It's not doing as I said it would. As I don't know why, I'll use the pointer approach again. just editted my response

Comment: BTW, in your first attempt you created a pointer and assigned it to the address of you variables, to pass this pointer as argument in the functions. You don't need to create that, you can use &variable directly